# Reference Portable Class Library (PCL) from ASP.NET 5 Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, asp.net-core, portable-class-library, asp.net5

I am using VS 2015.

I have created a PCL project. Class Library Portable (IOS, Android and Windows).

This PCL is a simple POCO class.

It targets: 
.NET Framework 4.5, ASP.NET Core 1.0, Windows Phone Silverlight 8, 
Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.IOS

My PCL is referenced by a Xamarin.IOS app and I want to use the same PCL in my Web API.

I am trying to reference this PCL project from an ASP.NET 5 Web API.

The following is in my project.json:

"dnx451": {
  "dependencies":
   {
     "MyPCL": "1.0.0-*" 
   }
}

--> Error: The Dependency could not be resolved.

I have tried adding the following under frameworks too but no luck.

```
".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile111": {

    "dependencies": {
         "MyPCL": "1.0.0-*"
       }

  "frameworkAssemblies": {
    "mscorlib": "",
    "System": "",
    "System.Core": ""
  }
}
```

I have also tried dnu restore.. still does not work.

Quick update:

Yesterday I upgraded to RC2.

It does not resolve the issue. in project.json now i have:

```
   "dependencies": 
   {
       "NETStandard.Library":  "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
   }
```

and I added the following under framework:

```
"netstandard1.5": {
  "imports": "dnxcore50"
}
```

when I compile my Web API project I get the following 3 errors:

1. the project has not been restored or restore failed. (though I did run dotnet restore)
2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
3. Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETStandard,Version=v1.5' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue please?

Is it even possible to reference this PCL from an ASP.NET 5 Web API or MVC 6 project?

Comment: Please upgrade to ASP.NET Core RC2 first, http://dot.net Then use the new framework names and imports statements to consume existing PCL libraries. RC1 is dead and you should leave it behind.

Comment: I upgraded to RC2. no luck.

project.json:

   "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library":  "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  } 

I added the following under framework: 

    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }

Comment: when I compile my Web API project I get the following 3 errors: 

1. the project has not been restored or restore failed. (though I did run dotnet restore)

2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.

3. Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETStandard,Version=v1.5' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. the question was referencing one PCL library by both: IOS App and .NET Core MVC. As to NETStandard.Library this is a formal specification of .NET APIs to be available on all .NET runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best approach is to:

Upgrade this `PCL` to a `netstandard 1.3+` library. This however would force you to create/upgrade to a `netcore 1.0+` MVC/API application to consume as `interface INetCoreApp10 : INetStandard15` is the best analogy to think of with `netcore` projects(Current version is 1.1).

For more information on how to upgrade, you can view the following: https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-library-support-for-xamarin/

Please note that if you do this, you can also use the `Compatibility Shim` to reference other PCLs inside the `netstandard` library.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library#pcl-compatibility

To answer your question:

> Is it even possible to reference this PCL from an ASP.NET 5 Web API or MVC 6 project?

Yes it is. There are many ways to do it and I personally think the correct way is to use the "new" bits such as `netstandard` and `netcore` in this situation. Based off my answer you have multiple things you can do:

1. Upgrade the PCL to `netstandard` and the API project to `netcore`. The `netcore` project can easily consume the `netstandard` project.
2. Upgrade the API project to `netcore` and use the `Compatibility Shim` to reference old PCL Profiles.
3. Stay using pre-`netcore/netstandard` project types and consume the PCL in a `ASP.NET MVC 5 Web API project`. This is also known as a `netframework` project rather than `netcore`. i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/choosing-core-framework-server